# CDC on Sql Server 2017 with HA cluster stopped working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, change-data-capture

I am currently using Sql Server 2017 (14.0.3294.2) running on Windows Server 2016 as an HA cluster, one primary with two secondaries.

A few days ago, the primary was rebooted and I think the person that did it executed some operations that made the primary server primary again. Since then, CDC stopped working. Querying the cdc tables doesn't offer a clue about the status. The CDC job is enabled.

I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744083/cdc-is-enabled-but-cdc-dbotable-name-ct-table-is-not-being-populated, however, I am very reluctant to use the solution in this context.

The last error in the CDC job log is (after the primary was restarted):

> Executed as user: UserName. Failed to update database "DatabaseName"
> because the database is read-only. [SQLSTATE 25000] (Error 3906).
> NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of times (10) without
> succeeding.  The step failed.

Any suggestions on how to make CDC work again?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the problem is generated by the fact that the database is not primary.
In fact it is read-only state. Try to fail back the relative AG group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

About the cdc job you need to have it in every node that of the AG cluster.
Take a look at how to manage cdc in an alwayson environment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: At on point the primary server, let's call it Server A, lost it's "primary" status. After this point I think CDC stopped working. Then it became primary again but CDC is still not working. Thank you for the links. I will read them.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do is start the job running on the primary server using `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'cdc.DbName_capture';`

The nice thing is that it caught up with all the changes made since the job went down.

Comment: Echoing your answer. I've found that the SQL Agent job can just die for no apparent reason. Restarting the job allows CDC to catch up. As long as it hasn't been down for more than the CDC retention period no data is lost.